# How to create/simulate creation of deserialization exception when using schema registry ( in addition to brokers and zookeepers)

Tags: spring-kafka

We are using spring-kafka-2.2.7.RELEASE to produce and consume avro messages and using schema registry for schema validation with 'FORWARD_TRANSITIVE' as the compatibility type.  Now, I'm trying to use 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer2 ' from spring-kafka to handle the exception/error when a deserializer fails to deserialize a message. Now I'm trying to write a component test to test this configuration. My component test expected to have below steps.

1. Spin up a local kafka cluster using docker containers
2. Send an avro message (using KafkaTemplate) with invalid schema to re-create/simulate the deserialization exception onto a test topic

Now what's happening is, since we have schema registry in place, if i send a message with new schema (invalid schema) it's validating the schema as per the compatibility type setting we have and not letting me producer the message onto kafka by throwing an exception at the producer level itself.

Now my question is, In this scenario, how can I create/simulate the creation of deserialization exception to test my configuration. Please suggest.

Note:- I don't want to disable/stop schema registry because that wouldn't simulate our prod setup.

Comment: Why don't you just send some junk message directly to the topic (no avro)?

Comment: sure, I'll give a try and see what happens, I'm not sure if that would help if the serializer from the producer end might fail if it accepts only avro messages. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Since it's a test case; simply create a new producer with a `StringSerializer` to send the junk record.

Comment: sure, would try that. Thanks

Comment: I tried this and it's throwing an exception like 'Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id -1'. Thanks for the inputs @Gary